# useEffect in React Not Triggering as Expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I start my code I have an error: "Cannot convert null value to object" because I can not update my store with `useEffect`.

I can not find a reason why the code show the error.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { currencyExchangeListSelectors } from "../../store/selectors";
import { setCurrencyExchangeList } from "../../store/thunk";
import { formatterСurrency } from "../../utils/helpers";
import style from "./style";

const CurrencyExchange = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect");
    dispatch(setCurrencyExchangeList());
  }, []);

  const currencyExchangeList = useSelector(currencyExchangeListSelectors);
  const { buy, sale, ccy } = currencyExchangeList[1] || {};
  const saleUSD = formatterСurrency(sale);
  const buyUSD = formatterСurrency(buy);

  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <Text>
        {" "}
        {ccy} {saleUSD} / {buyUSD}{" "}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CurrencyExchange;
```

> ```
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object
>
> This error is located at:
>     in CurrencyExchange (created by Main)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by Main)
>     in Main (created by App)
>     in Provider (created by App)
>     in App (created by withDevTools(App))
>     in withDevTools(App)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in AppContainer
>     in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
> ```

Comment: const { buy, sale, ccy } = currencyExchangeList[1] || {};
issue is in the line where the value can be null. check if the value is there and assign